# Best way to share multiple flags between angular components

Tags: angular, angular5

I have multiple angular components each needs to share some flags(some are numeric values as well) and changes to those flags should be applied to other components as well.

Following example somewhat resembles my problem. For now, I am using a EventManager(similar to https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/master/src/service/event-manager.service.ts), to propagate changes to other components.

```
@Component({
 selector: 'parent',
 templateUrl: './parent.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
flag1:boolean; flag2:boolean; flag3:booean; flag4:boolean; flag5:boolean;
private setFlag1Subscriber:Subscription;
// similary for other flags

constructor(private eventManager: EventManager) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.subscribeSetFlag1Event();
 }

 private setFlag1(flag1) {
  this.flag1 = flag1;
 }

 private subscribeSetFlag1Event() {
  this.editRefreshScenarioEvent = this.eventManager.subscribe(
      'setFlag1Event',
      (response) => this.setFlag1(response.content)
    );
 }
 ngOnDestroy() {
  this.eventManager.destroy(this.setFlag1Subscriber);
 }
}
```

This way if I include more flags the code becomes bulky and hard to read.

Child components will broadcast the corresponding event to set that flag as follows:
I can use @Input and @Output since i have multiple level child's that doesn't seem to be feasible either(it may happen that flag5 is only modified by 4th level child)

```
@Component({
     selector: 'first-level-child1',
     templateUrl: './first-level-child1.html'
})
export class FirstLevelChild1Component {
 @Input() flag1: booean;

 constructor(private eventManager: EventManager) {}

  OnClickChangeFlag1() {
   this.eventManager.broadcast({
       name: 'setFlag1Event',
       content: this.flag1
   });
  }
}
```

This way I have multiple level child's where these flags are needed, and there are some new flags which should be shared at same level. For e.g. flag6, flag7 should be shared between FirstLevelChild1Component & FirstLevelChild2Component. Like this I have lots of flags and each change should be propagated to other components.

Can anyone propose better way to implement this, like a shared service which holds all these flags and any change in flags updates other components

Comment: you can use `ngrx-store` for all these management

Comment: Can you please give me a _sample code_ as in to illustrate how do you implement above example.

Comment: Follow this [**medium**](https://medium.com/@aravindfz/setting-up-storemodule-in-ngrx-4-0-b7c60732aa64) blog. Please let me know if you need more help